# JSON comparison function

Tags: javascript, json

I've written a comparison function between two json values. I'd like to know if it can be improved at all in any way. Thanks again for the help.

```js
/*
    JSON will compare in the following order:

        - null
        - bool
        - number
        - string
        - array (on values, then on array length (shorter is less)
        - object (convert to array of sorted k-v pairs, and compare as array)

    Note that JSON and Structs treat object/struct keys differently. 
    In JSON, {'a': 1, 'A': 2} contains two keys, whereas in SQL it would only have one.
    For example, BigQuery and Postgres treat structs keys case-insensitively.
    When comparing among JSON values, object-keys will always be treated as case-sensitive.

    By default we will compare strings case-sensitively. However there will be a
    flag to allow case-sensitive sorts on strings. 

    The signature is:
        compareJsonValues(
                val1: null|bool|number|array|object, 
                val2 null|bool|number|array|object,
                case_insensitive: bool
        ) -> -1, 0, or 1 

    EXAMPLES
    Note: every below output will evaluate to true. 
    Every value is implied to be json. For example, 2 < 3 in SQL would be JSON 2 < JSON 3.

        null < false, false < 2, 2 < "h", "h" < [], [] < [1], [1] < [[]], [1] < [1,2],
        [] < {}, {} < {"a": 1}, {"a": 1} < {"a": {}}, {"a": 1, "b": 2} = {"b": 2, "a": 1},
        {"a": 0, "z": 1} < {"a": 1}, {"a": 0} < {"a": 0, "b": 0}

*/

"use strict";

const TYPE_RANK = {
    "null": 1, 
    "boolean": 2, 
    "number": 3, 
    "string": 4, 
    "array": 5, 
    "object": 6
};

function getType(val) {
    /* acceptable types are: ["boolean", "number", "string", "object"]
      otherwise return "other" */
    switch (typeof val) {
        case "boolean":
        case "number":
        case "string":
            return typeof val;
        case "object":
            return val === null ? "null" :  Array.isArray(val) ? "array" : "object"
        default:
            return "other"
    }
};

function comparisonToNumberHelper(val1, val2) {
    return val1 === val2 ? 0 : val1 > val2 ? 1 : -1;
}

function compareJsonValues(val1, val2, case_insensitive) {
    // 1 -- make sure the inputs are of acceptable type
    let [type1, type2] = [getType(val1), getType(val2)];
    if (type1 === "other" || type2 === "other") {
        throw new Error(`Unacceptable type supplied -- Val1: "${type1}" | Val2: "${type2}"`);
    };

    // 2 -- return result if of different types
    if (type1 !== type2) {
        return comparisonToNumberHelper(TYPE_RANK[type1], TYPE_RANK[type2]);
    }

    // 3 -- now compare them for real if of the same type
    if (type1 === "null" || type1 === "boolean" || type1 === "number" || type1 === "string" && !case_insensitive) 
        return comparisonToNumberHelper(val1, val2);
    else if (type1 === "string" && case_insensitive) {
        return comparisonToNumberHelper(val1.toLowerCase(), val2.toLowerCase());
    }
    else if (type1 === "array") {

        for (let i=0; i < val1.length; i++) {

            // Because we are using the length of val1.
            // If we have gotten to an index where val1 has
            // a value, but val2 does not, return 1 (val1 > val2)
            if (val2[i] === undefined) {
                return 1;
            }

            let subres = compareJsonValues(val1[i], val2[i], case_insensitive);
            if (subres !== 0) return subres;
        }
        // All (if any) values compared so far are equal
        // So return 0 if they two arrays are also the same length
        return val1.length === val2.length ? 0 : -1;
    } 

    else if (type1 === "object") {
        
        // Compare are an array of sorted k-v pairs. 
        // Note again that keys are always sorted case-insensitively.
        // Example:
        // {"a": 1, "b": 2} = {"b": 2, "a": 1}
        // [["a", 1], ["b", 2]] = [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
        
        let entries1 = Object.entries(val1).sort((a,b)=> a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
        let entries2 = Object.entries(val2).sort((a,b)=> a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
        return compareJsonValues(entries1, entries2, case_insensitive);
    }
}

const compareJsonValuesCI = (val1, val2) => compareJsonValues(val1, val2, 1);
const compareJsonValuesCS = (val1, val2) => compareJsonValues(val1, val2, 0);



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test code
let x = 
    [1,2,3,"a", null, [], {}, "B", 9, [1], [1,2], [1,3], ["a"], [{}], [[]],
    {"name": "david", "age": 20}, {"name": "david", "age": 18}, {"name": "david"}, {"age": 18}, {"age": 30}, {"age": 20}, {"age": {}}, {"age": 20, "bage": 24}
];
console.log(x.sort(compareJsonValuesCI));

const tests = [
    // (val1, val2, case_insensitive, result)
    [null, null, 0, 0],
    [true, false, 0, 1],
    [2, 4, 0, -1 ],
    ["b", "a", 0, 1],
    ["B", "a", 0, -1],
    [[], [], 0, 0],
    [{}, {}, 0, 0]
]
for (let [val1, val2, case_insensitive, expected_res] of tests) {
    let res = compareJsonValues(val1, val2, case_insensitive);
    if (res === expected_res) {
        console.log('OK')
    } else {
        console.log(`Error: Expected ${expected_res} but got ${res}.`)
    }
}
```

Comment: This might sound pedantic, but there's no JSON here. JSON is a string format. You have JSON-serializable JavaScript object/array data structures. Also, mixed-type arrays are usually an antipattern, as is runtime typechecking. In other words, the presence of `typeof` suggests a more fundamental design flaw. What use case is this code for?

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for the feedback and point on the JSON vs JSON-serializable. This is for sorting a bunch of user-entered json values. Something like an Excel column (with a bunch of json-serializable values) where a user can sort it ASC or DESC. They can enter in whatever they want -- mixed types, non-typed arrays, etc. -- we just have to provide a predictable and documented sort behavior.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw -- the code is the exact same. I added more accurate language to the comments so the intent is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The `array` check could be cleaned up. You should probably check length before looping over either of the lists (`if (val1.length !== val2.length) return val1.length < val2.length ? 1 : -1;`):

- If `val1.length + 1 === val2.length` (and if `val2.length` is a large N) currently it will loop several times before returning, this doesn't need to loop at all if the lengths aren't equal
- if `val1.length > val2.length` you don't need to loop and then also do the check after the loop
- if the lengths aren't equal the contents don't matter

Then you can remove the loop check for `undefined` and change the return to be just 0 as you have checked length and content equality already

```
else if (type1 === "array") {
    if (val1.length !== val2.length) return val1.length < val2.length ? 1 : -1; // ADDED
 
    for (let i=0; i < val1.length; i++) {

        // REMOVED

        let subres = compareJsonValues(val1[i], val2[i], case_insensitive);
        if (subres !== 0) return subres;
    }
    // All (if any) values compared so far are equal
    // So return 0
     return 0; //CHANGED
}
```

Full code:

```js
/*
    JSON will compare in the following order:

        - null
        - bool
        - number
        - string
        - array (on values, shorter length is less)
        - object (convert to array of k-v pairs, and compare as array)

    Note that JSON and Structs treat object/struct keys differently. 
    In JSON, {'a': 1, 'A': 2} contains two keys, whereas in SQL it would only have one.
    For example, BigQuery and Postgres treat structs keys case-insensitively.
    When comparing among JSON values, object-keys will always be treated as case-sensitive.

    By default we will compare strings case-sensitively. However there will be a
    flag to allow case-sensitive sorts on strings. 

    The signature is:
        compareJsonValues(
                val1: null|bool|number|array|object, 
                val2 null|bool|number|array|object,
                case_insensitive: bool
        ) -> -1, 0, or 1 

    EXAMPLES
    Note: every below output will evaluate to true. 
    Every value is implied to be json. For example, 2 < 3 in SQL would be JSON 2 < JSON 3.

        null < false, false < 2, 2 < "h", "h" < [], [] < [1], [1] < [[]], [1] < [1,2],
        [] < {}, {} < {"a": 1}, {"a": 1} < {"a": {}}, {"a": 1, "b": 2} = {"b": 2, "a": 1},
        {"a": 0, "z": 1} < {"a": 1}, {"a": 0} < {"a": 0, "b": 0}

*/

"use strict";

const TYPE_RANK = {
    "null": 1, 
    "boolean": 2, 
    "number": 3, 
    "string": 4, 
    "array": 5, 
    "object": 6
};

function getType(val) {
    /* acceptable types are: ["boolean", "number", "string", "object"]
      otherwise return "other" */
    switch (typeof val) {
        case "boolean":
        case "number":
        case "string":
            return typeof val;
        case "object":
            return val === null ? "null" :  Array.isArray(val) ? "array" : "object"
        default:
            return "other"
    }
};

function comparisonToNumberHelper(val1, val2) {
    return val1 === val2 ? 0 : val1 > val2 ? 1 : -1;
}

function compareJsonValues(val1, val2, case_insensitive) {
    // 1 -- make sure the inputs are of acceptable type
    let [type1, type2] = [getType(val1), getType(val2)];
    if (type1 === "other" || type2 === "other") {
        throw new Error(`Unacceptable type supplied -- Val1: "${type1}" | Val2: "${type2}"`);
    };

    // 2 -- return result if of different types
    if (type1 !== type2) {
        return comparisonToNumberHelper(TYPE_RANK[type1], TYPE_RANK[type2]);
    }

    // 3 -- now compare them for real if of the same type
    if (type1 === "null" || type1 === "boolean" || type1 === "number" || type1 === "string" && !case_insensitive) 
        return comparisonToNumberHelper(val1, val2);
    else if (type1 === "string" && case_insensitive) {
        return comparisonToNumberHelper(val1.toLowerCase(), val2.toLowerCase());
    }
    else if (type1 === "array") {
        if (val1.length !== val2.length) return val1.length < val2.length ? 1 : -1; // ADDED
 
        for (let i=0; i < val1.length; i++) {

            // REMOVED

            let subres = compareJsonValues(val1[i], val2[i], case_insensitive);
            if (subres !== 0) return subres;
        }
        // All (if any) values compared so far are equal
        // So return 0 if they two arrays are also the same length
        return 0; //CHANGED
    } 

    else if (type1 === "object") {
        
        // Compare are an array of sorted k-v pairs. For example:
        // {"a": 1, "b": 2} = {"b": 2, "a": 1}
        // [["a", 1], ["b", 2]] = [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
        let entries1 = Object.entries(val1).sort((a,b)=> a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
        let entries2 = Object.entries(val2).sort((a,b)=> a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
        return compareJsonValues(entries1, entries2, case_insensitive);
    }
}

const compareJsonValuesCI = (val1, val2) => compareJsonValues(val1, val2, 1);
const compareJsonValuesCS = (val1, val2) => compareJsonValues(val1, val2, 0);



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Test code
let x = 
    [1,2,3,"a", null, [], {}, "B", 9, [1], [1,2], [1,3], ["a"], [{}], [[]],
    {"name": "david", "age": 20}, {"name": "david", "age": 18}, {"name": "david"}, {"age": 18}, {"age": 30}, {"age": 20}, {"age": {}}, {"age": 20, "bage": 24}
];
console.log(x.sort(compareJsonValuesCI));

const tests = [
    // (val1, val2, case_insensitive, result)
    [null, null, 0, 0],
    [true, false, 0, 1],
    [2, 4, 0, -1 ],
    ["b", "a", 0, 1],
    ["B", "a", 0, -1],
    [[], [], 0, 0],
    [{}, {}, 0, 0],
    [[2], [2], 0, 0],
    [[2,2], [2,3], 0, -1],
    [[2], [], 0, 1],
    [[2], [3,3], 0, 1],
    [[2,8], [3], 0, 1],
    [{name:'john'}, {}, 0, 1],
    [{name:'john'}, {name:'jim'}, 0, 1],
]
for (let [val1, val2, case_insensitive, expected_res] of tests) {
    let res = compareJsonValues(val1, val2, case_insensitive);
    if (res === expected_res) {
        console.log('OK')
    } else {
        console.log(`Error: Expected ${expected_res} but got ${res}.`)
    }
}
```

Comment: we still need to compare if the lengths are different to see whether the first one is less than the second one. For example, `[1] < [2,3]` and `[3,4] > [2] `.

Comment: @David542 updated return to return value based on length with ternary operation

Comment: Ok, but look at the comment above. We compare element-wise **first** then length. Yours compares length first and then elements second. `[1,2]` should return less than `[3]`. Does that make sense? Yours returns the opposite.